# HTML 5 Canvas Drawing app

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

I made a small simple drawing app using HTML5 Canvas, learning how to use canvas.

You can right click to change color, scroll to change brush size, and click + drag to draw on the screen.

Any feedback is appreciated, but I am concerned about storing each move event circle that is created in an array may become quite messy eventually.

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, radius = 2) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.persist = [];
    this.color = "lightblue";
  }
  draw() {
    this.persist.forEach(e => {
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(e.x, e.y, e.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      c.fillStyle = e.color;
      c.fill();
    });
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
  }
}

const colors = [
  "#ffadad",
  "#ffd6a5",
  "#fdffb6",
  "#caffbf",
  "#9bf6ff",
  "#a0c4ff",
  "#ffc6ff",
  "#bdb2ff"
]

var c = null;
var canvas = null;
const main = function () {
  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  sizeCanvas();
  window.addEventListener("resize", sizeCanvas);
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    myCursor.x = event.x;
    myCursor.y = event.y;
    if (e.buttons == 1) {
      myCursor.persist.push({x: myCursor.x, y: myCursor.y, radius: myCursor.radius, color: myCursor.color});
    }
  });
  window.addEventListener("wheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const amountToChange = -1 * e.deltaY / 25;
    if (myCursor.radius + amountToChange < 1 || myCursor.radius + amountToChange > 50) return;
    myCursor.radius += amountToChange;
  }, {passive: false});
  window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myCursor.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
  });
  putCursorOnCanvas();
  // makeCanvasDrawable();
}

function sizeCanvas() {
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
}

const myCursor = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
function putCursorOnCanvas() {
  requestAnimationFrame(putCursorOnCanvas);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
  myCursor.draw();
}

function makeCanvasDrawable() {

}


window.onload = main;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  background-color: black;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>draw a line :D</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And why do you have this `persist` array? Why do you redraw everything in that array 60 times per second? I would say you don't even need the `requestAnimationFrame` if you just draw at the moment the mouse is "down" and then you can use the `mouseMove` event listener to draw. Because a canvas is persistent, you don't need to remember what was drawn before. (unless you want to add an undo function).